# How to impute NULL values to zero in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe in which some columns are of type String and contain NULL as a String value (not as actual NULL). I want to impute them with zero. apparently  `df.na.fill(0)` doesn't work. How can I impute them with zero?

Comment: I'm using Spark 1.6.0 , so replace doesn't exist there

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace()` from `DataFrameNaFunctions`, these can be accessed by the prefix `.na`:

```
val df1 = df.na.replace("*", Map("NULL" -> "0"))
```

You could also create your own `udf` that replicates this behaviour:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val nullReplacer = udf((x: String) => {
  if (x == "NULL") "0"
  else x
})

val df1 = df.select(df.columns.map(c => nullReplacer(col(c)).alias(c)): _*)
```

However this would be superfluous given it does the same as the above, at the cost of more lines of code than necessary.

Comment: it doens't replaces the null's. the resulting dataframe still has the 'null'!

Comment: I think ``.na`` only picks the cells that have actual null (missing value), ins't the case?

Comment: It should replace all values matching the key(s) in the replacement `Map()`.

Comment: this is the only way? any other alternative?